# Having a lot of copies of the same rigged character each posed differently. How to improve performance?

Tags: instances, performance, optimization

I am trying to make a scene which uses the same rigged character about 40 times but posed differently each time. It gets resource intensive and I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this since I am using the same mesh over and over again. Tried linking mesh data but it is kinda useless and duplicate linked doesn't work either. Maybe some other form of instancing?

Comment: Hello, why doesn't linked duplicate work?

Comment: If I'm doing it correctly (duplicate linked both mesh and armature selected) it has no effect both memory-wise and face count-wise compared to normal duplication

Comment: Mmh, weird, that's not what I see if I test it

Comment: could you please show me a clip, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Each mesh needs its own mesh data, because they have different deforms from their differently posed armatures.  Linking mesh data alone won't help much with performance-- will reduce file size significantly, may reduce system RAM usage by a small amount, but they still each need their copy of that data.  There's not a lot you can do that you couldn't do with 40 different characters.  Just make sure your materials are all linked copies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was afraid this may be the true answer, and was hoping there would be a creative solution of some sort. Maybe moonbots has a solution